# Passar valores do <option> JQuery Mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, html-select, html-option, jquery-remodal

Galera estou com uma dificuldade para realizar um submit de um campo especifico no caso o `<select>` com 3 `<option>`. Quando eu consigo que o campo insira algum dado no banco ele não traz o value, mas sim o a informaçao Undefined ou Object ( Pelo que eu entendi ele traz os dados Undefinido ou do tipo Object ) Na forma que o código está ele não está imputando os dados. Segue o código abaixo:

```
   function updatedata(str){

var id = str;
var nm = $('#nm'+str).val();
var gd = $('#gd'+str).val();
var pn = $('#pn'+str).val();
var al = $('#al'+str).val();
var nt = $('#nt'+str).val();
var nq = $('#nq'+str).val();
var me = $('#me'+str).val();
var sc = $('#sc option:select'+str).text();
var nr = $('#nr'+str).val();
var ob = $('#ob'+str).val();

var datas="nm="+nm+"&gd="+gd+"&pn="+pn+"&al="+al+"&nt="+nt+"&nq="+nq+"&me="+me+"&sc="+sc+"&nr="+nr+"&ob="+ob;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "php/updatedata.php?id="+id,
   data: datas
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#info').html(data);
  viewdata();
});
}
```

Os campos input text funcionam perfeitamente, mas somente o select box que não está funcional. Segue o select em html.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sc">status:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sc" >
        <option value='1'>Sim</option>
        <option value='2'>Não</option>
        <option value='3'>Revisar</option>
    </select>
```

Já tinha colocado tambem os values do html como texto em vez de numeros, mas também não houve o input.

Complementando essas informações são passadas para um Update set via modal, se eu altero qualquer campo dentro da modal é realizado o input mas somente o valor do `<select>` que não é inputado.

Grato desde já!

Galera, consegui inputar os dados com a resposta

```
var sc = $('select option:selected').text();
```

Mas aconteceu um problema que ele replica a informação do  de acordo com a quantidade de linhas do banco, exemplo:

Se o banco tiver 5 registros ele vai adicionar SimSimSimSimSim e nao somente Sim e se eu atualizar a informação com um Não ele fará NaoSimSimSimSim.

Agradeço se puderem me ajudar, irei postar o codigo completo com o html e o php, já não sei mais o que fazer para solucionar esse problema.

Grato.

```js
 <script>
    function viewdata(){
       $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/getdata.php"
      }).done(function( data ) {
   $('#viewdata').html(data);
      });
    }
    $('#save').click(function(){
 
 var nm = $('#nm').val();
 var gd = $('#gd').val();
 var pn = $('#pn').val();
 var al = $('#al').val();
 var nt = $('#nt').val();
 var nq = $('#nq').val();
 var me = $('#me').val();
 var sc = $('#sc').val();
 var nr = $('#nr').val();
 var ob = $('#ob').val();
 
 var datas="nm="+nm+"&gd="+gd+"&pn="+pn+"&al="+al+"&nt="+nt+"&nq="+nq+"&me="+me+"&sc="+sc+"&nr="+nr+"&ob="+ob;
      
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/newdata.php",
    data: datas
 }).done(function( data ) {
   $('#info').html(data);
   viewdata();
 });
    });
    function updatedata(str){
 
 var id = str;
 var nm = $('#nm'+str).val();
 var gd = $('#gd'+str).val();
 var pn = $('#pn'+str).val();
 var al = $('#al'+str).val();
 var nt = $('#nt'+str).val();
 var nq = $('#nq'+str).val();
 var me = $('#me'+str).val();
 var sc = $('select option:selected').text();
 var nr = $('#nr'+str).val();
 var ob = $('#ob'+str).val();
 
 var datas="nm="+nm+"&gd="+gd+"&pn="+pn+"&al="+al+"&nt="+nt+"&nq="+nq+"&me="+me+"&sc="+sc+"&nr="+nr+"&ob="+ob;
      
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/updatedata.php?id="+id,
    data: datas
 }).done(function( data ) {
   $('#info').html(data);
   viewdata();
 });
    }
    function deletedata(str){
 
 var id = str;
      
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/deletedata.php?id="+id
 }).done(function( data ) {
   $('#info').html(data);
   viewdata();
 });
    }
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Contrato</th>
     <th>Carteira</th>
     <th>Data Pagamento</th>
     <th>Valor Pagamento</th>
     <th>Parcelamento</th>
     <th>Quitação</th>
     <th>Envio</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Recuperador</th>
     <th>Observação</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ncontrato']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ncarteira']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['dpagamento']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['vpagamento']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['nparcelamento']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['nquitacao']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['menvio']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['scadastro']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['nrecuperador']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['observacao']; ?></td>
  
     <td>
     <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">Editar Linha</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

<form>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <p id="nm<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Contrato:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['ncontrato']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="gd<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Carteira:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['ncarteira']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="pn<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Data:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['dpagamento']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="al<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Valor:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['vpagamento']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="nt<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Parcelamento:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['nparcelamento']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="nq<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Quitação:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['nquitacao']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="me<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
     <b>Envio:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['menvio']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p id="nr<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>">
      <b>Recuperador:&nbsp;</b><?php echo $row['nrecuperador']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sc">status:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sc">
   <option>Sim</option>
   <option>Nao</option>
   <option>Revisar</option>
  </select>
  </div>
    
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ob">Observação:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ob<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['observacao']; ?>">
  </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="updatedata('<?php echo $row['id_acordo']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>     
     </td>
   </tr>
<?php
}
?>
 </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás a usar o seletor incorretamente.
Deves usar `#sc option:selected` e não `#sc option:select'+str`

Para saberes o `value` basta usares `$('#sc').val()`, para saberes o texto dessa option então deves fazer assim: `$('select option:selected').text()`.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8tqjLow/

Comment: ou `$(#sc).val()` também funciona! :D

Comment: @MarllonNasser exato, tenho isso na resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Ja que você utiliza jQuery use o find para buscar a opção selecionada assim:

```js
var itemSelecionado = $('select').find(":selected");

document.write(" <br> Texto do Item Selecionado :" + itemSelecionado.text());
document.write(" <br> Valor do Item Selecionado :" + itemSelecionado.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="sc">
  <option value='1'>Sim</option>
  <option value='2'>Não</option>
  <option value='3'>Revisar</option>
</select>
```